# Conflict between FK an PK Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to build a web app with Entity Framework core, I created two models `Category` an `Pie`, I do all things including DbContext an dependency injection, I created a `DbInializer` class to check if data base is empty and if this is true it will insert some data,the problem is when I run the app I get an exception, as if there is  conflict between primary key in Categories table and Foreign key in Pies Table, this is The Exception :

```
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The MERGE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Pies_Categories_CategoryId".The conflict occurred in database "ShopDb", table "dbo.Categories", column 'CategoryId'.
     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean & dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryHasMoreRows(Boolean & moreRows)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryHasMoreResults(Boolean & moreResults)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryNextResult(Boolean & more)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.Consume(DbDataReader reader)
ClientConnectionId: 775a7294 - 531a - 44cc - 8fbc - 29d293c339d5
         Error Number: 547,State: 0,Class: 16}
```

This is Pie class :

```
 public class Pie
 {
        public int PieId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ShortDescrition { get; set; }
        public string LongDescription { get; set; }
        public string AllegryInformation { get; set; }
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
        public string ImageThumbnailUrl { get; set; }
        public bool IsPieOfTheWeek { get; set; }
        public bool InStock { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

... here is Category class :

```
public class Category
{
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public List<Pie> Pies { get; set; }
}
```

The Configure method of th Startup class:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseStatusCodePages();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
            DbInitializer.Seed(app);
        }
```

DbInitializer class :

```
 public class DbInitializer
 {

        public static void Seed(IApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder)
        {
            AppDbContext context = applicationBuilder.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();
            if (!context.Categories.Any())
            {
                context.AddRange(
                        new Category { CategoryName = "First Pie", Description="Descriptionslqdfq vdfhsqdqsdhfs qsdhf" },
                        new Category { CategoryName = "Cheese Cackes", Description = "Descriptionslqdfq vdfhsqdqsdhfs qsdhf" },
                        new Category { CategoryName = "Saesonal Pie", Description = "Descriptionslqdfq vdfhsqdqsdhfs qsdhf" });
            }
            if (!context.Pies.Any())
            {
                context.AddRange(new Pie { Name = "Apple Pie", ShortDescrition = "short description", LongDescription = "Long description", AllegryInformation = "sflqjq", ImageUrl = "#", IsPieOfTheWeek = true, InStock = true, Price = 15.65M },
                    new Pie { Name = "Apple Pie", ShortDescrition = "short description", LongDescription = "Long description", AllegryInformation = "sflqjq", ImageUrl = "#", IsPieOfTheWeek = true, InStock = true, Price = 15.65M },
                    new Pie { Name = "Apple Pie", ShortDescrition = "short description", LongDescription = "Long description", AllegryInformation = "sflqjq", ImageUrl = "#", IsPieOfTheWeek = true, InStock = true, Price = 15.65M },
                    new Pie { Name = "Apple Pie", ShortDescrition = "short description", LongDescription = "Long description", AllegryInformation = "sflqjq", ImageUrl = "#", IsPieOfTheWeek = true, InStock = true, Price = 15.65M },
                    new Pie { Name = "Apple Pie", ShortDescrition = "short description", LongDescription = "Long description", AllegryInformation = "sflqjq", ImageUrl = "#", IsPieOfTheWeek = true, InStock = true, Price = 15.65M });
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }


 }
```

Comment: is this error comes when you insert?

Comment: Which way do you configure relations between your entites?

Comment: @Usman The exception occured when i call Seed method of DbInitializer class

Comment: @brut i used code first approach

Comment: You have to specify `Category` for the new `Pie`s.

Comment: How and where do you define foreign key? I don't see no data annotation,  no Fluent api.

Comment: @IvanStoev The CategoryId or the Category attrebute? wich one, i tried the CategoryId but still have the same problem.

Comment: @brut i define a Category attribute in Pie class, wich will be seen by Entity Framework as a foreign key will mapping between Models an Entities

Comment: I think you have to assign `Category` object retrieved from the context, because in case you are adding categories, the `CategoryId` s are not ready yet (until you call `SaveChanges`)

Comment: @IvanStoev yes you are right . it works now thanks  you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because you added

```
public int CategoryId { get; set; }
```

in `pie` Entity Framework handles relationship by its self when you add

```
public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
```

in your case when you added `CategoryId` it expects `categoryId` because its not set to null thats why its giving exception so you can either set `CategoryId` as `nullable int`

```
public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
```

or you can let entity framework handle it as a `nullable` for you